# Vuejs - change boolean if textarea not empty

Tags: vue.js, data-binding, textarea

I'm trying something i guess very simple :

```
<textarea name="ask" class="form-control" v-model="text"></textarea>
```

And the vue :

```
    data: {
      showLabel: true,
      text: ''
    },
    methods: {
      textareaValue(){
        return this.text
        if(this.text != '') {
          this.showLabel = false
        }
      }
    }
```

I can see the 'text' data value change in the console, but the showLabel boolean nerver turns to false as required in the test() method.

Any suggestion is very welcome.

Thanks !

Julien

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should check [computed properties](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html). It suits your use case.

You should declare the `showLabel` as a computed property and not in your data:

```
computed: {
  showLabel () {
     return !this.text
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you ! The showLabel made a label appear or disapear on focus and blur with focus and blur. So it seems that i can't make it disappear on focus if text is not empty